# gdb : How file find which parameters are the ones passed in?

Tags: assembly, java-native-interface, gdb

Working C and Java via JNI and making a SetObjectArrayElement call and running some test to answer some related gdb questions.

Here is the JNI call as used in C.

```
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, objArray, (jsize)i, obj1);
```

The code has caused a core and after disassembling the code it shows it fails on the mov command.

```
Dump of assembler code for function jni_SetObjectArrayElement:
   0x00002b514569f510 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00002b514569f511 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00002b514569f514 <+4>:     push   %r15
   0x00002b514569f516 <+6>:     mov    %rsi,%r15
   0x00002b514569f519 <+9>:     push   %r14
   0x00002b514569f51b <+11>:    mov    %rdi,%r14
   0x00002b514569f51e <+14>:    push   %r13
   0x00002b514569f520 <+16>:    mov    %rcx,%r13
   0x00002b514569f523 <+19>:    push   %r12
   0x00002b514569f525 <+21>:    mov    %edx,%r12d
   0x00002b514569f528 <+24>:    push   %rbx
   0x00002b514569f529 <+25>:    lea    -0x258(%rdi),%rbx
   0x00002b514569f530 <+32>:    sub    $0x48,%rsp
   0x00002b514569f534 <+36>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x00002b514569f53d <+45>:    mov    %rax,-0x38(%rbp)
   0x00002b514569f541 <+49>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x00002b514569f543 <+51>:    mov    0x2e8(%rbx),%eax
   0x00002b514569f549 <+57>:    cmp    $0xdeab,%eax
   0x00002b514569f54e <+62>:    je     0x2b514569f567 <jni_SetObjectArrayElement+87>
   0x00002b514569f550 <+64>:    mov    0x2e8(%rbx),%eax
   0x00002b514569f556 <+70>:    cmp    $0xdeac,%eax
   0x00002b514569f55b <+75>:    je     0x2b514569f567 <jni_SetObjectArrayElement+87>
   0x00002b514569f55d <+77>:    mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0x00002b514569f560 <+80>:    xor    %ebx,%ebx
   0x00002b514569f562 <+82>:    callq  0x2b5145a740f0 <_ZN10JavaThread18block_if_vm_exitedEv>
   0x00002b514569f567 <+87>:    mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0x00002b514569f56a <+90>:    callq  0x2b5145691bb0 <_ZN21ThreadStateTransition22transition_from_nativeEP10JavaThread15JavaThreadState.constprop.220>
   0x00002b514569f56f <+95>:    cmpq   $0x0,0x8(%rbx)
   0x00002b514569f574 <+100>:   mov    %rbx,-0x70(%rbp)
   0x00002b514569f578 <+104>:   movq   $0x0,-0x68(%rbp)
   0x00002b514569f580 <+112>:   je     0x2b514569f58b <jni_SetObjectArrayElement+123>
   0x00002b514569f582 <+114>:   lea    -0x70(%rbp),%rdi
   0x00002b514569f586 <+118>:   callq  0x2b514591bf90 <_ZN25WeakPreserveExceptionMark8preserveEv>
   0x00002b514569f58b <+123>:   nop
   0x00002b514569f58c <+124>:   test   %r13,%r13
=> 0x00002b514569f58f <+127>:   mov    (%r15),%r14   <-----Fails here
   0x00002b514569f592 <+130>:   je     0x2b514569f700 <jni_SetObjectArrayElement+496>
   0x00002b514569f598 <+136>:   mov    0x0(%r13),%r13
   0x00002b514569f59c <+140>:   test   %r12d,%r12d
   0x00002b514569f59f <+143>:   js     0x2b514569f638 <jni_SetObjectArrayElement+296>
   0x00002b514569f5a5 <+149>:   lea    0x928397(%rip),%rax        # 0x2b5145fc7943
   0x00002b514569f5ac <+156>:   movzbl (%rax),%edx
```

The "info reg" command is showing r15 as being a NULL value.

```
(gdb) info reg
rax            0x2b5145afa808   47628061485064
rbx            0x2b54538d2800   47641179006976
rcx            0x2b5424000a30   47640381229616
rdx            0x2b5424018c30   47640381328432
rsi            0x0      0
rdi            0x2b54538d2800   47641179006976
rbp            0x2b51935ed890   0x2b51935ed890
rsp            0x2b51935ed820   0x2b51935ed820
r8             0xf497fc9c       4103601308
r9             0x2b51480606f8   47628100699896
r10            0x398    920
r11            0x206    518
r12            0x0      0
r13            0x2b5424000a30   47640381229616
r14            0x2b54538d2a58   47641179007576
r15            0x0      0                        <---------NULL
rip            0x2b514569f58f   0x2b514569f58f <jni_SetObjectArrayElement+127>
eflags         0x206    [ PF IF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
```

Based only on the information provided, how can I tell which parameter is actually NULL?

The  "(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, objArray, (jsize)i, obj1)" call returns a void and passes in 4 parameters.

Reviewing the assembly code for jni_SetObjectArrayElement, would it be safe to assume the first 4 "mov" commands are moving the 4 parameters to the registers?

What is the other mov command doing?

```
   0x00002b514569f510 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00002b514569f511 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp    <------Parameter env?
   0x00002b514569f514 <+4>:     push   %r15
   0x00002b514569f516 <+6>:     mov    %rsi,%r15    <------Parameter objArray?
   0x00002b514569f519 <+9>:     push   %r14
   0x00002b514569f51b <+11>:    mov    %rdi,%r14    <------Parameter i?
   0x00002b514569f51e <+14>:    push   %r13
   0x00002b514569f520 <+16>:    mov    %rcx,%r13    <------Parameter obj1?
   0x00002b514569f523 <+19>:    push   %r12
   0x00002b514569f525 <+21>:    mov    %edx,%r12d   <----What is this one for?
   0x00002b514569f528 <+24>:    push   %rbx
   0x00002b514569f529 <+25>:    lea    -0x258(%rdi),%rbx
   0x00002b514569f530 <+32>:    sub    $0x48,%rsp
```

I ran the code in another scenario and the assembly code for jni_SetObjectArrayElement actually shows the following 4 mov commands instead of 5 as shown above. Why would that be?

```
Dump of assembler code for function jni_SetObjectArrayElement:
   0x00002b1c85caa2d0 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00002b1c85caa2d1 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00002b1c85caa2d4 <+4>:     push   %r15
   0x00002b1c85caa2d6 <+6>:     mov    %rsi,%r15
   0x00002b1c85caa2d9 <+9>:     push   %r14
   0x00002b1c85caa2db <+11>:    mov    %rdi,%r14
   0x00002b1c85caa2de <+14>:    push   %r13
   0x00002b1c85caa2e0 <+16>:    mov    %rcx,%r13
   0x00002b1c85caa2e3 <+19>:    push   %r12
   0x00002b1c85caa2e5 <+21>:    movslq %edx,%r12
   0x00002b1c85caa2e8 <+24>:    push   %rbx
```

Based on the below comments, I believe this is the proper reference...maybe.

```
   0x00002b514569f510 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00002b514569f511 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp    
   0x00002b514569f514 <+4>:     push   %r15
   0x00002b514569f516 <+6>:     mov    %rsi,%r15    <------Parameter env?
   0x00002b514569f519 <+9>:     push   %r14
   0x00002b514569f51b <+11>:    mov    %rdi,%r14    <------Parameter objArray?
   0x00002b514569f51e <+14>:    push   %r13
   0x00002b514569f520 <+16>:    mov    %rcx,%r13    <------Parameter i?
   0x00002b514569f523 <+19>:    push   %r12
   0x00002b514569f525 <+21>:    mov    %edx,%r12d   <----Parameter obj1 (address in low order bytes)
   0x00002b514569f528 <+24>:    push   %rbx
   0x00002b514569f529 <+25>:    lea    -0x258(%rdi),%rbx
   0x00002b514569f530 <+32>:    sub    $0x48,%rsp
```

Comment: Consult [calling convention documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI). Argument order is `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`. Neither `rsp` nor `rbp` is an argument. Note that these are already in registers,as to why the compiler decided to copy them to different ones we can't tell.

Comment: Thanks for the link. When you mention "Argument order is rdi, rsi, rdx..." does that mean parameter 1 is rdi and parameter 2 is rsi .....regardless of the order shown above?               Also, based on the argument registers, I only find 3 out of the 4 parameters passed.

Comment: `What is this one for` is the missing argument. `edx` is the low 32 bits of `rdx`. Yes, registers are determined by the prototype, not in what order you use them. How would the caller even know that.

Comment: Both are showing rsi then rdi in the stack. Shouldn't it be rdi then rsi?

Comment: The order in which they are **used** is irrelevant. In any case, it's not the arguments that are pushed on the stack, it's the previous value for the registers subsequently used to store a copy of the arguments for whatever reason.

Comment: I edited the original post to add another paragraph to rearrange the argument references based on the comments. Would you check them out to see if correct?

Comment: First argument is `env` that is in `rdi`. Second is `objArray` that is in `rsi`. Third is `i` that is in `rdx`. Fourth is `obj1` that is in `rcx`. Not sure why you have problem assigning arguments in order.

Comment: Because the response was a bit ambiguous and was not clarified when I asked in a subsequent comment, but now it is very clear. Thanks.